# Export MS SQL database as *.dbschema

Tags: database, export, sql-server-2008

We have a production database and visual studio 2010 database project. We had to make some changes in database schema. Unfortunately we don't have previous database schema file for production database. Is there a way to export existing database schema as *.dbschema file, preferably from Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (2008 R2)? This way we could run schema comparison and generate update script.